# Product carousel in the Google Search sidebar

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

What type of markup should a website use to have such a snippet in Google search results?

[image: big block to the right of search results]

In particular I mean the carousel with arrows. Can't find an example.

([Link to search results](https://www.google.de/search?q=alainclassmotors). Seems like the carousel is gone for now; it was there half a month ago.)